# Any solution for C# .Net with cucumber? Need to achieve same advantages what Ruby gives

Tags: c#, .net, cucumber

I want to use .Net C# for BDD tests and I have seen SpecFlow which is similar to Cucumber. But I want to use Cucumber with C#. Any solutions available? My concern here is "C# Cucumber should get same benefits what Ruby cucumber gives"

Comment: What is wrong with SpecFlow? It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/). Actually, DotNetRocks had [a show about Cucumber](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=921) recently where it was explained that SpecFlow is actually Cucumber.Net but the sponsors thought it would get better traction if it had a serious name.

A nuget search for SpecFlow will return numerous packages to integrate it with NUnit or TeamCity, additional runners etc

Comment: Thank you. So I will go ahead with it and do you suggest WatiN for web applications with these combinations?

Comment: That *is* an opinion-based question. It really depends on what you feel comfortable with.